# Alternate name for "Resources" section of a website

Tags: information-architecture, taxonomy, content-strategy

Simple question regarding labeling, I have a "Resources" section on a website that contains instruction manuals, technical specification documents and such. It also contains a couple of forms to request customized products.

I feel that the word "resources" makes it seem that the content within that category is secondary, but the forms for requesting customized products/services shouldn't necessary be considered secondary. But it's a client's request that the forms go under Resources. I was wondering if anyone had a better idea for renaming Resources

Comment: Welcome to UX.stackexchange. I would recommend that that you look at competitor's sites, use a thesaurus and see what's applicable. Ultimately it's the client's choice.

Comment: Yep, thanks, already did all that. Everyone usually calls it "Resources", and FYI, yes, it's the client's choice, except that I was asked to make alternate suggestions...'just looking around to see if anyone could come up with anything else. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a link must let the user know where it's linking to. If it's the only section of the website with ***downloads*** and ***documentation*** I'd go with either of those.

Comment: Yes, documentation or downloads both work (depending on the specifics of the site). I would also mention "Support", which often acts as the parent page for downloads, documentaion and contact info.